# How to append to a file inside a Script Block job?

Tags: powershell

Something is wrong with my desired output file.

I get a "null path" error,

```
No se puede enlazar el argumento al parámetro 'Path' porque es nulo.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-Content], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddContentCommand
    + PSComputerName        : localhost
```

If I move $outputReport inside the script block , sometimes appears a error saying the file "x" is in use by other process:

```
El proceso no puede obtener acceso al archivo 'C:\Users\mario\Desktop\Report700.csv' porque está siendo utilizado en otro proceso.
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Users\mario\Desktop\Report700.csv:String) [Add-Content], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetContentWriterIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddContentCommand
    + PSComputerName        : localhost
```

my source is a CSV like this:

```
pc1,user1
pc2,user2
pc3,user3
```

CODE:

```
$csvLocation = '~\desktop\test.csv'
$csv = import-csv $csvLocation -Header PCName, User

#Output File:
$outputReport = "~\Desktop\Report700.csv"

#desktop cuota:
    # info:
    # "209715200" Bytes = 200 MB
    # "1048576"   Bytes = 1   MB

$cuota = "209715200"
$cuotaTranslate = "$($cuota / 1MB) MB"

Write-Host "Cuota is set to $cuotaTranslate"

#ScriptBlock
$sb = {
    Param($computer, $username)

    if (!(Test-Connection -Quiet -count 2 -computer $computer)) { return }

        $w7path = "\\$computer\c$\users\$username\desktop"       
        $desktopSize = (Get-ChildItem -Recurse -force $w7path | Measure-Object -ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue" -property length -sum) 

        if($($desktopSize.sum) -gt $cuota){

            $newline = "{0},{1},{2}" -f $computer,$Username,"$("{0:N0}" -f $($desktopSize.sum / 1MB)) MB"
            $newline | Add-Content $outputReport
        }


}


$csv | % {
  Start-Job -ScriptBlock $sb -ArgumentList $_.PCName, $_.User
}

# wait for completion
do {
  Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
} while (Get-Job -State 'Running')

# cleanup
Get-Job | % {
  Receive-Job -Id $_.Id
  Remove-Job -Id $_.Id
}

Write-Host "All done!"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a [scope](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847849.aspx) issue here. The variable `$outputReport` inside your scriptblock is a different variable than the variable `$outputReport` in the script scope. If you want the variable inside the scriptblock to have the same value as the one outside, you need to pass that value into the scriptblock via the `-ArgumentList` parameter:

```
#ScriptBlock
$sb = {
    Param($computer, $username, $outputReport)
    ...
}

$csv | % {
  Start-Job -ScriptBlock $sb -ArgumentList $_.PCName, $_.User, $outputReport
}
```

However, doing this will create other problems, like concurrent access to the output file by multiple parallel jobs. You can avoid this by removing `| Add-Content $outputReport` from the scriptblock and writing all output to a file when you collect it from the completed jobs.

To do so remove this:

```
if($($desktopSize.sum) -gt $cuota){

    $newline = "{0},{1},{2}" -f $computer,$Username,"$("{0:N0}" -f $($desktopSize.sum / 1MB)) MB"
    $newline | Add-Content $outputReport
}
```

and add this:

```
Get-Job | % {
  Receive-Job -Id $_.Id
  Remove-Job -Id $_.Id
} | Out-File $outputReport
```

Answer (score 1):

Few thins I could point here is

Use absolute path name instead of relative path. Like

instead of saying

```
$csvLocation = '~\desktop\test.csv'
```

change it to

```
$csvLocation = 'C:\Users\blah_user\Desktop\test.csv'
```

change `$outputReport` in same way.

The below command

```
$newline = "{0},{1},{2}" -f $computer,$Username,"$("{0:N0}" -f $($desktopSize.sum / 1MB)) MB"
$newline | Add-Content $outputReport
```

can simply be said like

```
"{0},{1},{2}" -f $computer,$Username,"$("{0:N0}" -f $($desktopSize.sum / 1MB)) MB" | OUT-FILE C:\Users\blah_user\Desktop\Report700.csv
```

(OR) even better, just append the output to file like

```
"{0},{1},{2}" -f $computer,$Username,"$("{0:N0}" -f $($desktopSize.sum / 1MB)) MB" >>  C:\Users\blah_user\Desktop\Report700.csv
```